# Fill NaN of selected columns based on a dictionary whose keys are column names and values are content of anther column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the dataframe `df1` as follows:

```
         id  products  black metal  non-ferrous metals  precious metal
0  M0066350    copper          NaN                 NaN             NaN
1  M0066352  aluminum          NaN                 NaN             NaN
2  M0066353      gold          NaN                 NaN             NaN
3  M0066354    silver          NaN                 NaN             NaN
4  S0200837   soybean          NaN                 NaN             NaN
5  S0212350     Apple          NaN                 NaN             NaN
6  S0212351  iron ore          NaN                 NaN             NaN
7  S0212352      coke          NaN                 NaN             NaN
8  S0212353    others          1.0                 NaN             1.0
```

and I hope to fill columns `cols = ['black metal', 'non-ferrous metals', 'precious metal']` with `1`s based on `customized_dict`:

```
customized_dict = {
    'black metal': ['iron ore', 'coke'], 
    'non-ferrous metals': ['copper', 'aluminum'],
    'precious metal': ['gold', 'silver']
                   }
```

Please note the keys are from column names of `df1` and `values` are from content of `products` in `df1`.

So my question is how could I get the following output:

```
         id  products  black metal  non-ferrous metals  precious metal
0  M0066350    copper          NaN                 1.0             NaN
1  M0066352  aluminum          NaN                 1.0             NaN
2  M0066353      gold          NaN                 NaN             1.0
3  M0066354    silver          NaN                 NaN             1.0
4  S0200837   soybean          NaN                 NaN             NaN
5  S0212350     Apple          NaN                 NaN             NaN
6  S0212351  iron ore          1.0                 NaN             NaN
7  S0212352      coke          1.0                 NaN             NaN
8  S0212353    others          1.0                 NaN             1.0
```

**EDIT:** new data with duplicates in `products` column.

```
    id  products  black metal  non-ferrous metals  precious metal
0  S0212350     Apple          NaN                 NaN             NaN
1  M0066352  aluminum          NaN                 1.0             NaN
2  S0212352      coke          1.0                 NaN             NaN
3  S0212354      coke          1.0                 NaN             NaN
4  M0066350    copper          NaN                 1.0             NaN
5  M0066353      gold          NaN                 NaN             1.0
6  S0212351  iron ore          1.0                 NaN             NaN
7  S0212353    others          1.0                 NaN             1.0
8  M0066354    silver          NaN                 NaN             1.0
9  S0200837   soybean          NaN                 NaN             NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple loop on the columns and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
customized_dict = {
    'black metal': ['iron ore', 'coke'], 
    'non-ferrous metals': ['copper', 'aluminum'],
    'precious metal': ['gold', 'silver']
                   }
df.update(df.iloc[:,2:].apply(lambda c: c[df['products']
                                         .isin(customized_dict[c.name])]
                                         .fillna(1)))
```

output:

```
         id  products  black metal  non-ferrous metals  precious metal
0  M0066350    copper          NaN                 1.0             NaN
1  M0066352  aluminum          NaN                 1.0             NaN
2  M0066353      gold          NaN                 NaN             1.0
3  M0066354    silver          NaN                 NaN             1.0
4  S0200837   soybean          NaN                 NaN             NaN
5  S0212350     Apple          NaN                 NaN             NaN
6  S0212351  iron ore          1.0                 NaN             NaN
7  S0212352      coke          1.0                 NaN             NaN
8  S0212353    others          1.0                 NaN             1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
# list comprehension for MultiIndex Series with 1
L = [(x, k) for k, v in customized_dict.items() for x in v]
# reshape for DataFrame
df2 = pd.Series(1, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)).unstack()
# replace missing values by products column converted to index
df = df1.set_index('products').combine_first(df2).rename_axis('products').reset_index().reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
print(df)
         id  products  black metal  non-ferrous metals  precious metal
0  M0066350    copper          NaN                 1.0             NaN
1  M0066352  aluminum          NaN                 1.0             NaN
2  M0066353      gold          NaN                 NaN             1.0
3  M0066354    silver          NaN                 NaN             1.0
4  S0200837   soybean          NaN                 NaN             NaN
5  S0212350     Apple          NaN                 NaN             NaN
6  S0212351  iron ore          1.0                 NaN             NaN
7  S0212352      coke          1.0                 NaN             NaN
8  S0212353    others          1.0                 NaN             1.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I get an error for your third line code: `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`

Comment: @ahbon - change `df` to `df1` and `df1` to `df2`

Comment: Sorry for my late feedbacks, I get an error while running your third line: `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError` for my real data, I thinks bug has been happened since in my actual data, `products` column have duplicated values.

Comment: @ahbon - I can test.

Comment: @ahbon - for me working if change `fillna` to `combine_first`

Comment: It fills, but `products` column seems become empty. Is it possible keep as original?

Comment: @ahbon - if remove `.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)` it is not empty?

Comment: No, it not empty but we will lose `id` column.

Comment: @ahbon - pandas remove index name, so added `rename_axis`

Answer (score 2):

Create a reverse dict mapping and use `crosstab` to create the updated array then `fillna`:

```
reversed_dict = {v: k for k, l in customized_dict.items() for v in l}
df1 = df1.fillna(pd.crosstab(df1.index, df1['products'].map(reversed_dict), values=1, aggfunc='mean'))
print(df1)

# Output
         id  products  black metal  non-ferrous metals  precious metal
0  M0066350    copper          NaN                 1.0             NaN
1  M0066352  aluminum          NaN                 1.0             NaN
2  M0066353      gold          NaN                 NaN             1.0
3  M0066354    silver          NaN                 NaN             1.0
4  S0200837   soybean          NaN                 NaN             NaN
5  S0212350     Apple          NaN                 NaN             NaN
6  S0212351  iron ore          1.0                 NaN             NaN
7  S0212352      coke          1.0                 NaN             NaN
8  S0212353    others          1.0                 NaN             1.0
```